# What is wrong with the following piece of code?

Tags: python

Whenever i run the problem, it returns the value of the last arithmetic problem only, and the rest get lost.

the following is the link to the question:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/scientific-computing-with-python/scientific-computing-with-python-projects/arithmetic-formatter

The following is the code i wrote:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, show=False):
#maximum number of problems allowed are 5
    if len(problems) > 5:
        print('Error: Too many problems.')
    else:
        line1 = " "
        line2 = " "
        line3 = " "
        line4 = " "
        for p in problems:
            problem = p.split()
            fnumber = problem[0]
            operator = problem[1]
            snumber = problem[2]
            
            #operator should only contain '+' or '-'
            if operator != '+' and operator != '-':
                print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
            
            #Number cannot be more than 4 digits
            if len(fnumber) > 4 or len(snumber) > 4:
                print('Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits.')


            #finding length of the operands
            longest_number = max(len(fnumber),len(snumber))
            operator_position = longest_number + 2

        
            #operands should only be digits
            try:
                fnumber_int = int(fnumber)
                snumber_int = int(snumber)
            except:
                print('Error: Numbers must only contain digits.')

            
            #evaluating the answer
            if operator == '+':
                answer = fnumber_int + snumber_int 
            else:
                answer = fnumber_int - snumber_int 
            

            #arranging problems vertically
            line1 = line1 + fnumber.rjust(operator_position) + (4*' ')
            line2 = line2 + operator +snumber.rjust(operator_position - 1) + (4*' ')
            line3 = line3 + '-' * operator_position + (4*' ')
            line4 = str(answer).rjust(operator_position) + (4*' ')

            
            if show == True:
                arranged_problems = f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n{line4}"
            else:
                arranged_problems = f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}"
        
        return arranged_problems
```

Comment: You set arranged_problems inside the loop, and this discard its value and set it again the next time through the loop.  You need to initialize it before the loop, and then append to stuff to the end of it, not overwrite it completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code you created is, as Frank said, that you are overwriting the `arranged_problems` variable every time, instead of adding the new arranged problem to a list of arranged problems. The code below fixes this:

```
def arithmetic_arranger(problems, show=False):
    arranged_problems = []
#maximum number of problems allowed are 5
    if len(problems) > 5:
        print('Error: Too many problems.')
    else:
        for p in problems:
            problem = p.split()
            fnumber = problem[0]
            operator = problem[1]
            snumber = problem[2]
            
            #operator should only contain '+' or '-'
            if operator != '+' and operator != '-':
                print("Error: Operator must be '+' or '-'.")
            
            #Number cannot be more than 4 digits
            if len(fnumber) > 4 or len(snumber) > 4:
                print('Error: Numbers cannot be more than four digits.')


            #finding length of the operands
            longest_number = max(len(fnumber),len(snumber))
            operator_position = longest_number + 2

        
            #operands should only be digits
            try:
                fnumber_int = int(fnumber)
                snumber_int = int(snumber)
            except:
                print('Error: Numbers must only contain digits.')
                
            #evaluating the answer
            if operator == '+':
                answer = fnumber_int + snumber_int 
            else:
                answer = fnumber_int - snumber_int 
            
            #arranging problems vertically
            line1 = fnumber.rjust(operator_position) + (4*' ')
            line2 = operator +snumber.rjust(operator_position - 1) + (4*' ')
            line3 = '-' * operator_position + (4*' ')
            line4 = str(answer).rjust(operator_position) + (4*' ')

            arranged_problems.append(f"{line1}\n{line2}\n{line3}\n{line4}")
            if show == True:
                print(arranged_problems[len(arranged_problems)-1])
        
        return arranged_problems
```